# 'Proving recursion is impossible', how to handle such a question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Currently I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37064475) asks to prove using recursion to test if an array is palindrome, but I found a bit difficult to handle the question.

If I change the question to something like "how to use recursion to...", it may alter the intent of OP that requires proof instead of solution.

If I provide solution of recursion directly, it answers the questions as "yes, it is possible..." but seems not OP seeks for.

And I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2093618) which looks answer this question directly, but I don't know if it is a duplicate or just a related question.

What is the best way to answer/handle the question?answer? Flag as duplicate? Other actions required or no action need to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that you can just flag as a duplicate and see what the OP thinks. The OP sees a banner with the suggested duplicate and if they agree with it, they can close their question as a duplicate (although technically "Community" closes it).

Otherwise, I think the question should be closed as "Unclear what you're asking". I'm not sure if they wanted a mathematical/computer science style proof (the dupe you suggested), or "teh recursive codez" (what you thought they might be asking), or something completely different (code design?).

I don't think we had enough information to close it as too broad. Sometimes I think that "Too Broad" is just too broad of a close reason.